# Replicate data from Netsuite to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, netsuite

Currently the company I am consulting for is using Boomi to bring data from netsuite to SQL Server. The call takes about 8 hours. We would like it to be more real time. Any suggestions on what to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding one or more SuiteCloud Plus licenses to NetSuite lets you run more integrations at the same time. Each one adds 10 more to the base 5. This lets you can increase the "Maximum Number of Concurrent Connections" for the NetSuite connection on your Boomi processes.

To pull a lot of different NetSuite record types from NetSuite without having to build Boomi processes and SQL tables you can use a product like [Relational Junction for NetSuite](http://sesamesoftware.com/relational-junction/netsuite-backup/).

With either approach to get faster sync you have to pick which records/objects are more important and run them more often while leaving others to sync less often as the NetSuite SOAP API is fairly slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the SQL server, meaning you can write your own integration, I would highly suggest a RESTLet and/or just posting to the server from a user event from the records you want the data from. It's not difficult to do.

Or you could post the data directly to the server (not so much realtime) using SFTP and then the server can parse the file.

There are a lot of options. It really depends on your setup and what data you're trying to extract or sync.

Comment: Sorrry about the horrible explanation.  Basically I want to replicate all the data into sql server from the cloud.  The current connection is through Boomi but we would like to move away from that.  We do not currently have another connection and they want to charge a crazy sum for an ODBC connection so was just seeing if there was another way.  Also, yes I do have full access to SQL Server.

Comment: Adding the additional SuiteCloud licenses will definitely help no matter what integration you use. There are products that can do this for you and one I mention (in no way affiliated) is the Relational Junction for NetSuite. However, if you don't want to pay the subscription fees you can build your own.